# Can't access docker swarm clusters via ip running on docker-machines using hyper-v

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I can't access docker swarm clusters via ip running on docker-machines using hyper-v

I am following the getting started tutorial here: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#accessing-your-cluster
I managed to get everything running properly up until the accessing your cluster part. The output from all the commands seem correct, but when I try going to the ip listed it says the site can't be reached. What am I doing wrong?

The tutorial says this right after the section I'm having issues with: Having connectivity trouble? Keep in mind that to use the ingress network in the swarm, you need to have the following ports open between the swarm nodes before you enable swarm mode:
Port 7946 TCP/UDP for container network discovery.
Port 4789 UDP for the container ingress network.
I don't really understand what this means though, plus I have a feeling it's already done during the regular docker for windows install.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ended up finding a solution. I had the same problem and after some searching I came across the solution in the [docker machine GitHub](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4608).

Based on the suggestions provided in the thread, I tweaked the command provided from the docker tutorial to the following:

```
docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "DockerExternal" --hyperv-boot2docker-url "https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v18.09.1-rc1/boot2docker.iso" manager1
```

Change "DockerExternal" to the name of your external virtual switch and it should work.